# Vertica Query Result Export and Import using Python

Tags: python-2.7, vertica

I want to copy certain data from a Vertica cluster (lets say a test cluster) to another Vertica cluster (lets say QA cluster). Manually I can do this by dumping the result of a query into a CSV file and then importing it on the other cluster. But, how can I do it on a Python script without using os or system commands. I want to do it purely using some Python module or adapter. As of now I am using python-vertica adapter, I am able to connect to Test cluster and get the data into a python list, but I am unable to export it to a CSV file natively using the adapter (i.e. without using python csv module). Also, how can I import the CSV file in my QA cluster using the same adapter (or a different vertica module for python)?

Comment: it's possible, but _I_! need to understand what does it mean `python-vertica adapter`. Is it native connector or connector of  `Vertica` or it's driver of Uber? What is Vertica version?

Comment: python-vertica is a python library developed by Uber, it connects to Vertica. I am using Vertica v8.1.1-14

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do it with `COPY FROM VERTICA` for simple problems. Read [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPYFROMVERTICA.htm) for more info.
2. For python you can use in my template:

**Environment**:

- python=2.7.x
- vertica-python==0.7.3
- Vertica Analytic Database v8.1.1-10

**Source code example**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# coding: UTF-8

import csv
import cStringIO

# connection info: username, password, etc
SRC_DB_INFO = {...}
DST_DB_INFO = {...}

csvbuffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvbuffer, delimiter='|', lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

# establish connection to source database
connection = vertica_python.connect(**SRC_DB_INFO)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM A')

# convert data to csv format
for row in cursor.iterate():
    csvwriter.writerow(row)

# cleanup 
cursor.close()
connection.close() 

# establish connection to destination database
connection = vertica_python.connect(**DST_DB_INFO)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# copy data
cursor.copy('COPY B FROM STDIN ABORT ON ERROR', csvbuffer.getvalue())
connection.commit()

# cleanup 
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```